# RoR Deployment to heroku gone wrong, rake db:migrate won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, rubygems

I'm currently doing Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial, and although I've followed the instructions carefully, my app doesn't deploy to heroku properly. Help.

My Gemfile looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And I've typed in the following commands:

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

yet, my ending result looks like this: http://warm-wildwood-5691.herokuapp.com/
" The page you were looking for doesn't exist. "

these are my heroku logs

2013-07-19T19:21:15.363798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=safe-ridge-7992.herokuapp.com fwd="190.72.80.97" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=

2013-07-19T19:21:16.733481+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-ridge-7992.herokuapp.com fwd="190.72.80.97" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=

2013-07-19T19:21:36+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started

2013-07-19T19:24:23.872947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-ridge-7992.herokuapp.com fwd="190.72.80.97" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=0

Help?

Comment: What do the logs have?  That would be useful.

Comment: Try `heroku open`. What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check your logs. Log into your Heroku account and check your logs for more information.

Second, have you properly set up your remote for this application?

If not, make sure you are in your app's directory in your console, and do the following:

`git remote rm heroku` (In case you already had set it up improperly.)

Then you can do:

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:warm-wildwood-5691.git`

Then, run `git push heroku master` and `heroku run rake db:migrate` as you were doing previously.

Comment: It says your host is `safe-ridge-7992.herokuapp.com`. That's not the name of your app. Your local app must be pointing to a different Heroku app than the one you want it to go to.

Comment: However, that doesn't make sense considering that you just made sure the remote points to the correct app. Did you sign into the Heroku website to check your app's logs, or did you enter `heroku logs` into the console while in your app's directory?

Comment: I re-deployed another app, after I made the original question I deleted it. I entered heroku logs instead of checking Heroku's :)

Comment: Ah, are you saying that you deleted your warm-wildwood app? If so, have you made sure that the remote points to the new safe-ridge app?

Comment: Yes I deleted it, I think the remote points to the new safe-ridge app, because I deleted everything, the repo on github AND the local directory, I started from scratch just to make sure stuff like that didn't happened.

Comment: Did you create a Heroku repository for that app? See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) for more information.

Comment: I did! thanks for bearing for so long. Remember that I'm doing everything on the tutorial, I did created a heroku repo. If that weren't the case my app would look like "Heroku, welcome to your app" instead of giving me an error right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to push a branch of my repository to heroku. Somehow this doesn't "arrive". Merging into the master (git) and pushing up the master then worked as expected.